# NextJS throws error when I add a background video

Tags: background, next.js

I want to add background video, format mp4, but NextJS shows error:

```
./public/video/ocean.mp4 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently 
no loaders are configured to process this file. See 
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

(Source code omitted for this binary file)

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react"
import Layout from "../components/webSite/layout";
import backgroundVideo from "../public/video/ocean.mp4"

const Home = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      videoRef.current.play()
    },5000)
  }, []);

  return <Layout title={"Home"}>
    <video
        ref={videoRef}
        controls
        width="250"
        loop
        muted
        style={{
          position: "relative",
          width: "100%",
          height: "15rem",
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
        }}>
      <source src={backgroundVideo} type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  </Layout>
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 19):

Everything that you `import` in React actually needs a [webpack loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/) that understands the format.

MP4 is not one of those formats. Even if it was, importing an entire video file would be horribly inefficient :-)

Solution: Don't import the video file, instead reference it as an external file that the browser loads over http like any other media file. All files you put in `/public` can be referenced below the top folder of you web site:

```
<source src="/video/ocean.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

Contrary to the other answers, it is *not inefficient* to import an `.mp4` (using the right loader) and it doesn't require a NextJS-specific plugin.

Using [`file-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/), webpack will give you a URL as the import of your `.mp4`. Webpack simply copies the `.mp4` to the output directory (not *in* the bundle) and returns a relative URL to that. It will be requested normally when you use it in a `<video>` element.

To use `file-loader` for `.mp4`s, you can add a `webpack()` callback to your `next.config.js` like the below.

```js
export default {
webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    const prefix = config.assetPrefix ?? config.basePath ?? '';
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.mp4$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          publicPath: `${prefix}/_next/static/media/`,
          outputPath: `${isServer ? '../' : ''}static/media/`,
          name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
        },
      }],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Then simply import your `.mp4` and use it in a `<video>` element

```js
import myvideo from './myvideo.mp4';
export default function MyVideo(){
  return <video>
    <source src={myvideo} type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>;
}
```

If you're using Typescript, you'll also want to add a declaration for the file extensions that you're loading with `file-loader`. This should go in a `.d.ts`, Next.js [recommends (scroll down to find the info box mentioning it)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#existing-projects) making `additional.d.ts` and then adding it to your TS config `include` property.

```
// additional.d.ts
declare module '*.mp4' {
  export default string;
}
```

This is basically what ]`next-videos` does](https://github.com/jeremybarbet/next-videos/blob/master/index.js) under the hood too.

Comment: Is there any benefit in importing the file using a webpack loader versus referencing the image from the public folder directly?

Comment: If you're importing using file-loader, it basically does the same thing as putting it in public, it's just a bit more "webpack-y". Considering a loader is just a function behind the scenes, there might also be a special loader for .mp4s out there that does optimization (like next's built in image loader does srcset stuff and other optimizations). You could also make your own .mp4 optimization loader fairly easily and hook it up to something like ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Cobertos. It's working properly on my localserver (and I can see in the local build that the files end up in the same folder as other images), but the files don't seem to be making it to production. I'm not sure if this is related to the loader, or instead because the component rendering the videos is a client component, and something weird is maybe happening there? If you have any ideas I'd appreciate it : )

Comment: @WaldoFrank Hmm, sounds like something with your production deployment. As long as the output video file's relative position to the .html file is the same in production as your local deployment, it should work fine. The file-loader is not that smart, it just copies the file to the output directory and returns string pointing to the resource. Are you seeing any particular errors in production, and the expected path showing up in <source>, and the video output at the expected path that matches with <source>?

Comment: @Cobertos hanks for clarifying the separation between the file loader and the build process. I also tried loading videos with https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-videos, and again they weren't included in the build. So I'm assuming it's some kind of build setting where Next.js excludes .mp4 files by default? The file paths are directly referenced in the code, and the file paths are rendered in the production build, but the files themselves are missing. Not sure if that sounds unlikely or what, but I can't figure out what else could be happening.

Comment: "File paths are directly referenced in the code" they must be inside a `require()` or part of an `import` statement (and in `url()` in css files with css-loader). Webpack only sees dependencies, and the loaders are only applied to these dependencies that webpack defines. If you're just using a `src={"path/to/video.mp4"}` it will not work, you have to `src={require("path/to/video")}` or import at the top of the file. If you have an array, you have to use require.context to package up an entire folder programmatically

Comment: @WaldoFrank I just changed the path on this line and it worked on the production build too.  `outputPath: '${isServer ? '../../' : ''}static/media/',`. There seems to be a difference on working directory on production build where it says `isServer`. Not sure what is the cause thou :)

Comment: Last one broke the dev server path, so I ended up with something like this `outputPath: \`${isServer ? '../' : ''}${dev ? '' : '../'}static/media/\`,`. Also make sure you add the boolean dev config parameter at the second line like this `webpack(config, { isServer }) {`

Answer (score 5):

If the first answer won't work then try this:

**Install** a Package called

```
next-videos
```

After Installing go to your **next.config.js** File in your project and do this:

```
const withVideos = require('next-videos')
module.exports = withVideos()
```

Important is that after editing your config file you have to **restart** the server if you don't it won't work either.

In your File, you have to use `require()` in your component

For Example like this:

```
 export default () => (
   <div>
       <video src={(require('./video.mp4'))}/>
   </div>
  )
```

*All Information are used from npm.js website:*

*https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-videos*