# How to display a local video in Next JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I tried multiple ways to display a local video from assets folder but I'm getting the same error

`./assets/videos/video.mp4 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.`

I tried to add it like this
`<video src={require("./../assets/videos/video.mp4").default} />`
but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us your webpack config

Comment: have you add this file on public folder?

Comment: i don't know if this can be done. Instead try put the video in a public folder and then just do the old way, `<video src="URL" />`

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Next Js background mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63852351/1870780)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must put your video file inside the public folder and then you can play it in your component like this :

```
 <video controls src={"/filename.mp4"} style={{ width: "400px", height"400px" }} />
```