# How do I import an m4v video into a create-next-app with typescript?

Tags: typescript, video, next.js

I'm getting the following error:

```
./components/Hero.tsx:2:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '../media/HeroVideo1-Red-Compressed.m4v'
  1 | import React, { useState } from 'react';
> 2 | import Video from '../media/HeroVideo1-Red-Compressed.m4v';
  3 | import { Button } from './SharedStyles';
  4 | import styled from 'styled-components'
  5 | import { MdKeyboardArrowRight, MdArrowForward } from 'react-icons/md';

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/index.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

my `tsconfig.json` file has the following:

```
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

I've tried adapting the top answer (by score) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759220/importing-images-in-typescript-react-cannot-find-module) by adding `index.d.ts` to `./media` with the declaration `declare module '*.m4v'` and that worked in getting rid of the squigly lines in `Hero.tsx` but then generated the error above on the client side.

I've also tried both answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649879/nextjs-throws-error-when-i-add-a-background-video/73729543#73729543) and that didn't help either. I'm trying to avoid putting the video in the `public` folder. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of trying various solutions from other stackoverflow questions, I finally found one that worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649879/nextjs-throws-error-when-i-add-a-background-video?rq=1). I added the following to `nextConfig` in `next.config.js`:

```
webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    const prefix = config.assetPrefix ?? config.basePath ?? '';
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.mp4$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          publicPath: `${prefix}/_next/static/media/`,
          outputPath: `${isServer ? '../' : ''}static/media/`,
          name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
        },
      }],
    });
```